Maximize function with SymPy - crank rod application
I want to know the worst case for a crank rod application.

The force Ft in the connecting rod is given by:

And I want to know its maximum.
I tried to solve it either on Wolfram Alpha or with SymPy. See the following code :
import sympy as sym
# import numpy as np
r, l, A = sym.symbols('r, l, A', positive = 'True')
B= sym.asin(r/l*sym.sin(A))
f = sym.simplify(sym.sin(A+B)/sym.cos(B))
df=sym.simplify(sym.diff(f,A))
sln=sym.solveset(df,A, sym.Interval(0, sym.pi))

it gives me, that
Complement(ConditionSet(_R, Eq((-l + r*sin(_R))**2*(l + r*sin(_R))**2*(l**4*cos(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))**2 - 2*l**2*r**2*sin(_R)**2*cos(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))**2 + 2*l**2*r**2*sin(_R)*sin(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))*cos(_R)*cos(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l)) - l**2*r**2*cos(_R)**2*cos(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))**2 + r**4*sin(_R)**4*cos(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))**2 - 2*r**4*sin(_R)**3*sin(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))*cos(_R)*cos(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l)) + r**4*sin(_R)**2*sin(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))**2*cos(_R)**2 + r**4*sin(_R)**2*cos(_R)**2*cos(_R + asin(r*sin(_R)/l))**2), 0), Interval(0, pi)), Union(Intersection({0}, ImageSet(Lambda(_n, -I*(I*(2*_n*pi + arg(sqrt(-2*l**2 - 2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r) + r**2))) + log(Abs(sqrt(-2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r)/r**2 + (-2*l**2 + r**2)/r**2))))), Interval(0, pi))), Intersection({0}, ImageSet(Lambda(_n, -I*(I*(2*_n*pi + arg(sqrt(-2*l**2 + 2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r) + r**2))) + log(Abs(sqrt(2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r)/r**2 + (-2*l**2 + r**2)/r**2))))), Interval(0, pi))), Intersection({0}, ImageSet(Lambda(_n, -I*(I*(2*_n*pi + arg(-sqrt(-2*l**2 - 2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r) + r**2))) + log(Abs(sqrt(-2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r)/r**2 + (-2*l**2 + r**2)/r**2))))), Interval(0, pi))), Intersection({0}, ImageSet(Lambda(_n, -I*(I*(2*_n*pi + arg(-sqrt(-2*l**2 + 2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r) + r**2))) + log(Abs(sqrt(2*l*sqrt(l - r)*sqrt(l + r)/r**2 - (2*l**2 - r**2)/r**2))))), Interval(0, pi)))))
I don't know what is _n and Lambda ?
Could you please help me ?

from sympy import *

r, l, A, L, t = sym.symbols('r, l, A, L, t', positive = 'True')
B= sym.asin(r/l*sym.sin(A))
f = sym.simplify(sym.sin(A+B)/sym.cos(B))
df=sym.simplify(sym.diff(f,A))

# replace r/l with L and expand trig funcs and rewrite in terms of tan
# and then replace tan(A/2)**2 with x

eq=df.subs(r,l*L).factor().expand(trig=True).rewrite(tan).subs(tan(A/2)**2,x)


# take the numerator and factor - it gives 3 factors

z = list(ordered(eq.as_numer_denom()[0].factor().args))
print(solve(z[0].base,x)) # (x + 1)**42
print(solve(z[1].base,x)) # (-4*L**2*x + x**2 + 2*x + 1)**19

# remove radicals from z[2]

from sympy.solvers.solvers import unrad
u = unrad(z[2],x)[0] # there is no change of var

# extend z with the new x-containing factors

z[-1:]=collect(u.factor(),L).as_independent(x)[1].args
print(solve(z[2].base,x))

This gives the 3 trivial solutions for x which is defined as tan(A/2)**2. It is left as an exercise to show that none of them is a valid solution.
[-1]
[2*L**2 - 2*L*sqrt(L**2 - 1) - 1, 2*L**2 + 2*L*sqrt(L**2 - 1) - 1]
[-1]

z[3] is quadratic in L**2 and is a 6th order polynomial in x.
numerical solutions
It will be easy to get solutions for a given L:
>>> [i.n(3) for i in real_roots(z[-1].subs(L,S.Half))]  # r/l = L in [0,1]
[-2.99, -0.335, 0.450, 2.22]

And now solve those for A given the above definition. Since unrad was used, one should check the roots in the original equation, however, to see that they are valid.
implicit symbolic solutions
Let's get the implicit solutions and check them.
>>> Lsol = [sqrt(i) for i in solve(z[-1],L**2)]

# check that numerators of eq are zero when these solutions are used

>>> check = [eq.subs(L,li).simplify().as_numer_denom()[0] for li in Lsol]

# simplify under assumptions that sqrt args combine

>>> [powsimp(i,force=1).subs(x,t).factor(deep=1) for i in check]
[t + Abs(t - 1) - 1, t + Abs(t - 1) - 1]

So it looks like the implicit relationships will be valid as long as t = tan(A/2)**2 is in [0,1].
explicit symbolic solutions
Instead of rewriting in terms of tan it is possible to write in terms of cos:
>>> unrad(df.as_numer_denom()[0].expand(trig=1).subs(sin(A)**2,1-cos(A)**2).subs(cos(A),x).subs(r,l*L))[0].subs(x**2,y).factor()
-l*(L - 1)*(L + 1)*(L**2*y - L**2 + 1)**2*(L**4*y**3 - 3*L**4*y**2 + 3*L**4*y - L**4 + L**2*y**2 - 2*L**2*y + L**2 - y)
>>> _.as_independent(y)[1]
(L**2*y - L**2 + 1)**2*(L**4*y**3 - 3*L**4*y**2 + 3*L**4*y - L**4 + L**2*y**2 - 2*L**2*y + L**2 - y)


Only the last two factors depend on y = cos(A)**2 and it is cubic in y so an explicit solution can be found; only positive values should be selected for y.

Thank you, it took me time to undestand all the parts but now I have the solution of A for all r/l
